# Copy function Linked list c++

Tags: c++, list

I'm trying to write a function to copy the contents of one linked list into a new linked list (no reference to the first LL).
I've so far got this:

```
void List::copy(const List& otherList)
{
    assert(head == nullptr);
        if (otherList.head != nullptr)
        {
            head = new Node;
            assert(head != nullptr);
            head->item = otherList.head->item;
            Node* ptr1 = head;
            for (Node* ptr2 = otherList.head->next; ptr2 != nullptr; ptr2=ptr2->next)
            {
                ptr1->next = new Node;
                assert(ptr1->next != nullptr);
                (ptr1->next)->item = ptr2->item;
                (ptr1->next)->next = ptr2-> next;
            }
        }
}
```

However when I run the code on a small linked list, it simply copys the first and last nodes - for some reason it misses out the middle part. I've spent a while researching other peoples solutions and trying to figure out whats going wrong with mine, however i've hit a brick wall!

Could someone possibly point out where i'm going wrong?

Kind regards

Craig

Comment: You don't move `ptr1` (in other words, it always points to `head`). Thus you get the head and tail into your new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not iterating down you new list.

```
void List::copy(const List& otherList)
{
    assert(head == nullptr);
        if (otherList.head != nullptr)
        {
            head = new Node;
            assert(head != nullptr);
            head->item = otherList.head->item;
            Node* ptr1 = head;
            for (Node* ptr2 = otherList.head->next; ptr2 != nullptr; ptr2=ptr2->next)
            {
                ptr1->next = new Node;
                assert(ptr1->next != nullptr);
                (ptr1->next)->item = ptr2->item;
                ptr1 = ptr1->next;
            }
            ptr1->next = 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code never updates the value of `ptr1`.  It stays equal to `head` and you constantly update the new `head`'s `->next`, leaking allocated `Nodes` into limbo.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Node* ptr1 = head;
for (Node* ptr2 = otherList.head->next; ptr2 != nullptr; ptr2=ptr2->next)
{
    ptr1->next = new Node;
    assert(ptr1->next != nullptr);
    (ptr1->next)->item = ptr2->item;
    (ptr1->next)->next = ptr2-> next;
}
```

To this:

```
for (Node* ptr2 = otherList.head->next, ptr1 = head; ptr2 != nullptr; ptr2 = ptr2->next, ptr1 = ptr1->next)
{
    ptr1->next = new Node;
    (ptr1->next)->item = ptr2->item;
    (ptr1->next)->next = nullptr;
}
```

This change will initialize both of your iterators *only* in the `for` loop, and will advance them in lockstep.